# Nginx rule to fwd request to another location directive

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

request comes for /fr-fr/results i have to redirect to location /results. this is working fine now. But user is able to hit /fr-fr/results and also /results. How to restrict user not to use /results

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [internal keyword](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal) for the `/results`-location.